# Is it possible to reuse a CCHmacContext?

Tags: java, ios, macos, reusability

You can reuse the Java Mac object: you initialize it and can then call update/doFinal repeatedly without creating a new Mac instance.

On the other hand Win32 hash handles are single instance objects. You have to create a new one each time.

It appears that CCHmacContext objects are like Win32 handles rather than the Java Mac object. They work fine the first call but after that not so much. The Apple developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCHmac.3cc.html) today is silent on the matter and my [search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=reuse%20cchmaccontext) of StackExchange for *reuse CCHmacContext* produced no hits.

Does any one know whether CCHmacContext can be reused and, if so, how to go about it?

Comment: Why are you concerned about creating a new context each tine with `CCHmacInit'? Or just using the one-shot `CCHmac`?

Comment: I would use a more efficient approach if one were available. I assume reusing the context would be more efficient if that approach is available. Out of curiosity why wouldn't I be concerned?

Comment: But that is the problem, premature optimization, per Don Knuth: "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." Kent Beck: “Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work”

Comment: I just timed 1,000,000 iterations of `CCHmacInit(&ctx, kCCHmacAlgSHA256, key, 24);` in 0.638.29 sec, that is < 1 usec per init.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the optimizing aspect of this. I've seen the operation performed one way in Java and another in Windows and was curious about the possibilities in IOS/OS X. In fact "wondered" would probably be more accurate than "concerned" or "worried". And I don't think it's too wild and crazy to consider whether making the equivalent of two API calls rather than three might be worth some investigation, particularly if it's going to happen very frequently.

Comment: You can make one API call: *Stateless, one-shot HMAC function*: `CCHmac(
    CCHmacAlgorithm algorithm,
    const void *key,
    size_t keyLength,
    const void *data,
    size_t dataLength,
    void *macOut)`

Comment: That's true. In it you may be doing the work of three but it is one call. I'm assuming that each time you make that call you have to repeat the process of creating the context, initializing it, and then reversing the process and destroying itI imagine it costs something but you seem to believe it's not material. I get it.

Comment: The thing about optimizations is to measure the entire app, find the problem areas and attack them. I have seen keyboard code optimized when the limiting factor was the person typing. On an OS port after instrumenting it turned out the `memcpy` routine was taking 60% of the CPU time, a completely unexpected area of concern. By finding the areas of real performance issues real improvement can be made, in the case `memcpy` the time in it was reduced to < 10%. Measure and respond. Better putting time into clean simple code.